# Treat NA as zero in mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, na

`df <- wiot_02_14 %>%
  spread(partner_ctry, value) %>%
mutate(EA19=ifelse(P_EA19==1,AT+BE+CY+EE+FI+FR+DE+GR+IE+IT+LV+LT+LU+MT+NL+PT+SK+SI+ES,NA))`

As you can (hopefully) see, I want to create a new variable `EA19` which is the sum of 19 other variables in the dataset, but only for those columns where another variable `P_EA19` takes the value of 1. All other observations in `EA19` are supposed to be NA.

The problem: Some of the summands take NA, too. But when there are NAs in a calculation the outcome is NA as well.

What is the easiest way to tell R within this command to treat NAs as zeros or (second-best option) to replace all NAs with zeros. I tried to play around with replace_na and mutate_each, but couldn't produce a satisfactory solution.

I know that similar questions have been brought up before, but none of those could provide exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Either use `rowSums` with its NA-handling argument or or convert your data to long format, I'd say

Comment: You could use sum(AT, BE, CY, ...., na.rm = TRUE) as your true element.